# Why isn't the code for this button to go to web page working?

Tags: flash, adobe, animate-cc

I'm working Adobe Animate and I've been looking for a solution to this issue, but haven't been able to find anything. I'm new to coding in general, but have some experience.

What I'm trying to do is have a button link to a website and all the code I've been able to find hasn't been able to make it work. All I need it to do is function by clicking the button and it go to the page in a new tab. I tried the code snippet and got an error, but I've resolved that now and the button won't work.

See the code below.

function btn1Click(evt:MouseEvent):void {

var url:String = "https://www.discovergreece.com/en/wellness-and-spas";

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

navigateToURL(req);

}

Any assistance is appricated.

Comment: I shouldv'e noted, I'm working in Action Script 3.0

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I came to is to simply remove the button I made and make is a transparent box that covered the whole animation stating from frame 1 then used the code snippet for AS3 and it worked.